# TypeError: grid_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, python-3.5

```
prompt = ">>"
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
userName = Entry()
myLabel = Label(root, text="UserName")

userName.grid(row=0)
myLabel = Label.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

TypeError:
 grid_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: What are you attempting to do in this statement:  `Label.grid(...)` ?

Comment: Positions the widget in the grid format

Comment: which widget do you think it positions?

Comment: The Label Variable named "myLabel"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is incorrect:

```
myLabel = Label.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

At the very least it needs to be this:

```
myLabel = Label().grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Though, if you want `mayLabel` to be anything other than `None` you need to use two lines:

```
myLabel = Label()
myLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Though, if you want to use the previous definition of `myLabel`, maybe you need to simply omit `myLabel = Label()`, since that creates a new empty label.

Answer (score 0):

`Label.grid()` is the name of the method/function in the documentation. To use `.grid()`, do `mylabel.grid(...)`.

This is because `Label` represents the Class itself - you want to use a certain label, namely `mylabel`.