# I'm getting this error after clicking an operator in my Calculator GUI: TypeError: button() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

I'm working on a calculator GUI. I recently asked the same question. [TypeError: button() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68157821/typeerror-button-missing-1-required-positional-argument-number)
But it got closed as there was a similar question.
[How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920302/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-button-command-in-tkinter)
All the answers I got helped. And I was able to fix my problem. I tried running the program and it worked.

I was able to run the code without errors and in fact, it even shows the GUI. The issue is when I try clicking an operator.

If I click an operator like plus, minus, divide or multiply, it throws me this error.

```
C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
"C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Calculator GUI v1.0.py"
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\Python3.9\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Calculator GUI v1.0.py", line 40, in 
<lambda>
button_addition =       Button(root_var, text="+", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())
TypeError: button() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'
```

I get this error only when I click on an operator. I have no issues when clicking a number.
I've put a screenshot to show what's happened.
[image: This is the screenshot]

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import *

root_var = Tk()
root_var.title("Calculator")

e = Entry(root_var, width=25, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

def button(number):

e.delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, END)


button_1 = Button(root_var, text="1", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(1))
button_2 = Button(root_var, text="2", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(2))
button_3 = Button(root_var, text="3", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(3))
button_4 = Button(root_var, text="4", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(4))
button_5 = Button(root_var, text="5", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(5))
button_6 = Button(root_var, text="6", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(6))
button_7 = Button(root_var, text="7", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(7))
button_8 = Button(root_var, text="8", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(8))
button_9 = Button(root_var, text="9", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(9))
button_0 = Button(root_var, text="0", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(0))

button_addition =       Button(root_var, text="+", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())
button_subtraction =    Button(root_var, text="-", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())
button_multiplication = Button(root_var, text="*", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())
button_division =       Button(root_var, text="/", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())
button_exponents =      Button(root_var, text="^", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())

button_equals = Button(root_var, text="=", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())
button_clear =  Button(root_var, text="C", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())




button_1.grid(row=3, column=2)
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3, column=0)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=2)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=0)

button_7.grid(row=1, column=2)
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=0)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)
button_addition.grid(row=4, column=1)
button_subtraction.grid(row=4, column=2)

button_multiplication.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_division.grid(row=5, column=1)
button_exponents.grid(row=5, column=2)

button_equals.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_clear.grid(row=5, column=1)

root_var.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error has obviously told you what the problem is.  You have passed an argument to `button()` for `button_1` to `button_0`.  Why don't you do the same for other buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write def button (number=None):
You issue is solved

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import *

root_var = Tk()
root_var.title("Calculator")

e = Entry(root_var, width=25, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

def button(number=None):
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, END)


button_1 = Button(root_var, text="1", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(1))
button_2 = Button(root_var, text="2", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(2))
button_3 = Button(root_var, text="3", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(3))
button_4 = Button(root_var, text="4", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(4))
button_5 = Button(root_var, text="5", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(5))
button_6 = Button(root_var, text="6", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(6))
button_7 = Button(root_var, text="7", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(7))
button_8 = Button(root_var, text="8", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(8))
button_9 = Button(root_var, text="9", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(9))
button_0 = Button(root_var, text="0", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button(0))

button_addition =       Button(root_var, text="+", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())
button_subtraction =    Button(root_var, text="-", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())
button_multiplication = Button(root_var, text="*", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())
button_division =       Button(root_var, text="/", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())
button_exponents =      Button(root_var, text="^", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())

button_equals = Button(root_var, text="=", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())
button_clear =  Button(root_var, text="C", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda:button())




button_1.grid(row=3, column=2)
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3, column=0)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=2)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=0)

button_7.grid(row=1, column=2)
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=0)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)
button_addition.grid(row=4, column=1)
button_subtraction.grid(row=4, column=2)

button_multiplication.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_division.grid(row=5, column=1)
button_exponents.grid(row=5, column=2)

button_equals.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_clear.grid(row=5, column=1)

root_var.mainloop()
```